# identity server load balancing logout issue

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, identityserver4

i am working on identity server 4 with .net core micro service architecture, i have followed this reference application please click [Here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers).i have also used docker container to deploy distributed approach application.its working fine when it is in development i.e local environment.

but on production i am using Load balancing on identity server, because of load balancing i am facing log out issue.

Ex . i have created 3 instances of Identity server for production purposes i.e A,B and C, based on user load it will automatically switch between instances.Now the problem is when user logged in A instances after few seconds it automatically  requests to B or C instances because of load balancing, so problem is user logged in A instance and current request is handled by B or C instance so how server will know that user is logged in or not,that's why its logging out me and redirects to log in screen.

EDIT :
[Please check with Identity server configuration and operational store with signin certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7CJN.png)

Comment: How are you "logged in" to your identity server - it doesn't log you in, it returns an access token, are you using JWT or Reference tokens? If you're using Reference tokens how are you persisting them?

Comment: i am using default mvc identity for login in identity server and for clients access i am using app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions{}) for authentication with identity server

Comment: Are your tokens being persisted, or held in memory? If persisted, then where?

Comment: please check with my code of **Identity server** Startup.cs file which is  attached [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7CJN.png) , so you will be get better idea

Comment: Or you could just answer the question, even if it was with "I don't know"

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you have is due to the data protection in asp.net core, each container will be using different keys to encrypt / decrypt data. To verify just run one instance of the container, if this resolves your problem then look at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/

```
public class XmlToDbRepository : IXmlRepository
        {
            private readonly IPersistKeyDb _persistKeyDb;

            public XmlToDbRepository(IPersistKeyDb persistKeyDb)
            {
                _persistKeyDb = persistKeyDb;
            }

            public IReadOnlyCollection<XElement> GetAllElements()
            {
                return _persistKeyDb.GetAll().Select(i => XElement.Parse(i.Key)).ToList().AsReadOnly();
            }

            public void StoreElement(XElement element, string friendlyName)
            {
                _persistKeyDb.Store(friendlyName,element.ToString(SaveOptions.None));
            }
        }
```

I think this is the one you'll be interested in.